# Unable to see arangodb logs using web interface

Tags: windows-10, arangodb

I am unable to see logs using the web interface. 
Clicking on the Green squares seen in the image below has no effect. Also the "Load older Entries" button is always disabled.

Notice the error message in the screenshot.

> No suitable log entries found

[image: ArangoDb_Logs]

#### Background

Following ArangoDb's [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Administration/WebInterface/Logs.html) I should be able to see the logs of my running database on this page of the web interface.

Here is an image of what I should be seeing:
[image: Here is an image of what I should be seeing]

I'm trying to view the logs to trobleshoot another issue I'm having: [ArangoDb Lock timeout memory crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47351490/635160)

## Background

This is a fresh install of Arango Enterprise v3.2.7 on a Windows 10 64-bit desktop. With about 11 gigs of RAM. Installed with all the defaults (RocksDB), and is run without embellishments or parameters.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Doesn't the screenshot show some log messages? Can you clarify what logs or log messages exactly are missing from your point of view? Thanks!

Comment: I've added background info about my probelm for ppl unfamiliar with Arangodb

Comment: Thanks. Still unsure because the screenshot shows some log entries... I see it says "no suitable log entries found", but what actually did you attempt? Did you use any of the filters, or is that message always occurring even though the startup logs are displayed there (as visible in the screenshot). It's hard to guess otherwise.

Comment: I see your confusion, I've updated my question. Clicking those green squares has no effect. It does not seem (or is documented) as those green squares as being filters.

Comment: @Stj, I'm expecting something related to the import that had been running for 50mins before crashing out. I'm trying to troubleshoot this error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47351490/635160

Comment: Seems like the web ui can't find your log files. Have you started the server with any optional parameters or perhaps a file permission issue?

Comment: No, I haven't. Its a fresh install of enterprise with all defaults. I run it with just the `arangodb` run from an elevated command.

Comment: The log functionality in the web interface fetches the logs via an HTTP REST API call to the arangod server. And the arangod server has the last portions of the logs in memory, so it won't read them from files at all. So I can rule out a file permissions issue here. 
And I can confirm that clicking the green squares in the web interface has no effect. Just asked the original implementor of it and he said the green squares are not supposed to work as filters. The only way to filter is to use the "Level" and "Topic" filters on the right side of the screen, above the log messages.